# add another view into an already existing view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I already created a header.html.erb view in a rails app and want to add it to different views.  How could require other view to render it, could it be done without creating another controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= render "shared/header" >
```

assuming your header lived in `app/views/shared/_header.html.erb`

Answer (score 3):

Set it up as a partial.  Change the name to _header.html.erb, then, in each file you want the header in, render a partial

```
<%= render "header" %>
```

The other option would be to set up a layout with that header in it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a separate controller. If you would like to apply the header to all your pages simply add it to your application.html.erb that lives in your layout.

or as the following shared, You can create a partial and render it in your controller action  that corresponds to the view